# How to simply save a CSV file into a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Simply, I have a script that allows me to upload a CSV file from a HTML form and save it as an array in PHP. This script is working great, although I require my CSV file to be saved as a multidimensional array.

**This is how my CSV file will look:**

```
question1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
question2,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
question3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
```

**This is in order on what the elements should be saved as:**

```
uploaded[1][1],uploaded[1][2],uploaded[1][3],uploaded[1][4],uploaded[1][5]
uploaded[2][1],uploaded[2][2],uploaded[2][3],uploaded[2][4],uploaded[2][5]
uploaded[3][1],uploaded[3][2],uploaded[3][3],uploaded[3][4],uploaded[3][5]
```

**This is my working upload script**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['savecsv']))
{
    $csv_array = Array();
    $file = fopen($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    if($file){
        while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
          //$line is an array of the csv elements
          array_push($csv_array,$line);
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
}

?>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="upload_file" />
 <input type="submit" name="savecsv"/>
</form>
```

I know that arrays start at a value of 0, although this CSV is a upload version to add questions to my website quiz. The way I have setup the rest of my code will only process from [1][1] upwards. No point going into detail why since that is off topic, but it is just how I require it to be done. Therefore, I believe that all [0]'s should be left blank.

Also, each line will always have 5 elements per line. Never more or never less.

I have searched far and wide online, yet I can't seem to find a suitable answer for this.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're currently trying to do is not a good way to approach this problem and I'd recommend changing the rest of your code to use the proper array indexes. However, instead of simply pushing `$line` to `$csv_array`, you *can* do this:

```
$csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
```

Full code:

```
if(isset($_POST['savecsv']))
{
  $file = fopen($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
  if($file) {
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
    }
    fclose($file);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => question1
            [2] => answer1
            [3] => answer2
            [4] => answer3
            [5] => answer4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => question2
            [2] => answer1
            [3] => answer2
            [4] => answer3
            [5] => answer4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => question3
            [2] => answer1
            [3] => answer2
            [4] => answer3
            [5] => answer4
        )

)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Saw it had a down vote for some reason. Not to sure why. I upvoted since it was very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Off topic to my question, but how to you get the var_dump to output like that? Mine is printing my whole array on one line.

Comment: @fizzix: Output them in `<pre>` tags, like so: `echo '<pre>',print_r($csv_array),'</pre>';`

Answer (score 0):

Your will need to `array_unshift`

```
array_unshift(0, $line);
```

so your records stats with index 1 and having 0 at the 0 index. also initialized your `$csv_array` as follows

```
$csv_array = array(array());
```

Comment: @DevZer0 - Sorry mate, but that doesn't answer my question. I need a new loop that makes my array into a multidimensional array like the format I specified.